# Javascript file do not function if it cannot find elements from document

Tags: javascript, html

Recently, I have been working on a bug for a long amount of time. After some time, I managed to locate the issue and solve it but I didn't understand why there was a bug. Am I doing it incorrectly?

For example My directory structure: 
Build 
-- index.html 
-- about.html 
-- contact.html 
-- app.js

So all three HTML documents called the same external app.js file.

Using jQuery, I have this

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

$('#img1').... // some other functions here. #img1 is only found in index.html


$('#foo').hide(); // hiding the div. #foo is in all the HTML files in the directory.

}
```

The problem comes now -> #foo is hidden in index.html but was not hidden in about.html and contact.html

When I delete the `$('#img1')` and its functions from app.js, #foo is then hidden in all three HTML files. It seems that since `about.html` and `contact.html` cannot find a id called #img1, the rest of the script is redundant.

I managed to do a work around by having `$('#foo').hide();` going before `$('#img1')`....

However, I'm super curious why is this the case? Shouldn't jquery not care if #img1 can't be found and move on to the next functions,etc? In the case, does this mean I cannot minify my scripts in one single app.js? Am i missing something. *PS I'm not a javascript pro.

Update (31Aug) -> Sorry guys, I think i found out the issue. It's something to do with Greensock Animation Platform (only Timeline)

```
var slide1 = document.getElementById('slide-1'),
slide2 = document.getElementById('slide-2'),
slide3 = document.getElementById('slide-3'),
slide4 = document.getElementById('slide-4'),
slide5 = document.getElementById('slide-5');

var slideArray = [slide1, slide2, slide3, slide4, slide5];

var tl = new TimelineLite({}),
    delayTiming = 2.5,
    fadeTiming = 2;

tl
.to(slideArray, 0, {opacity:0})
.to(slide2, fadeTiming, {opacity:1, delay:delayTiming})
.to(slide3, fadeTiming, {opacity:1, delay:delayTiming})
.to(slide4, fadeTiming, {opacity:1, delay:delayTiming})
.to(slide5, fadeTiming, {opacity:1, delay:delayTiming, onComplete:fadeOutLastSlide});
```

Somehow tl can't find the slideArray (or its children) and when it cannot find any elements and causes the script below it not to function?

Should i delete this post?

Comment: There's not enough information. Setup a fiddle to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: It sounds like you either have multiple IDs on the same page or an error is keeping `$('#foo;).hide()` from executing. Show some markup or put up a fiddle.

Comment: Provide html from each page

Comment: Seems like somewhere in the

// some other functions here. 
You may have an error that is stopping the rest of the script from continuing. You need to post more of the code so that we can single out the error.

Answer (score 3):

You may use

```
if($('#img1').length){
    // code goes here
}
```

So, the action will occur only if there is a matching element on the current page. Also, the whole script stops working if any error occurs in the script.